# How to insert a line after and before a line which contains a word in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Hi I am using Notepad++ v6.3. I have a file which contains a function at many places with different params. I want to put some wait time before and after that function. So, basically I am looking for a way to insert a line before and after a line which contains a specific word. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do so using regular expression.
press ctrl+h .
in find box keep:

```
    (.*func_name.*)
```

and in replace box keep:

```
      \1\r\nxxx
```

where xxx is the new line contents to be added after the func_name(function name.)

Similarly if you want to add before the line, you can do so replacing the same with:

```
       xxx\r\n\1.
```